# Calculate average of variable between two dates based on a different date column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set similar to the xdata tibble below.  I'd like to calculate the average of the values variable when the month of the start date is different than the month of date, between dates defined by start date and start date five days after.

[EDITED FOR CLARITY]

```
library(lubridate)
library(tibble)

xdata <- tibble(date=ymd('2015-01-01')+days(seq(1:(365*3))), values=seq(1,365*3))

xdata <- xdata %>% mutate(start_date = case_when(wday(date)==2 ~ date+days(14))) %>% 
         fill(start_date)

xdata %>% mutate(avg = case_when(month(start_date) != month(date) ~ mean(values[between(date, start_date, start_date+days(5))])))
```

I've also tried

```
xdata %>% group_by(start_date) %>% mutate( . . .
```

but that does not solve the problem.

What I'm expecting is the following:
The first non-NA start_date occurs in row 4 and is start_date='2015-01-19'

I'd like to calculate the mean of the values (the column of data) for date='2015-01-19' and the next 4 days.  Those values are 18,19,20,21 and 22.  The mean should be 20.

[image: Average the 5 values in dates determined by start_date]

What is the best way to calculate the average of values between dates defined by a range based on start_date?

Thanks,

jfd118

ANSWER -
Jon Spring led me to this being the solution:

```
xdata %>%
  filter(!is.na(start_date)) %>%
  mutate(avg = slide_index_dbl(values, date, mean, .before=1, .after = 5)) %>%
  select(start_date = date, avg) %>% 
  right_join(xdata ) %>% 
  select(date, values, everything()) %>%
  arrange(date) %>% View()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the question yet. What should the output be when the start date month matches the date month? What do you want the output to look like? Can you give an example?

Comment: Thanks Jon.  When month(start_date) != month(date) I’d like to calculate the average of the variable “values” over 5 days starting from start_date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using `slider`, which is great for windowed calcs like this. I couldn't figure out how to skip the slider calc for NA start_date rows, so this filters them out and then brings them back in with a join:

```
library(slider); library(lubridate); library(dplyr)
xdata %>%
  filter(!is.na(start_date), month(start_date) != month(date)) %>%
  mutate(avg = slide_index_dbl(values, start_date, .after = 4, mean)) %>%
  right_join(xdata) %>% arrange(date)
```

EDIT:

I think I understand now. Here I'm calculating the "current + next 4 days avg" using `date`, and then renaming that `start_date` to join to the original data.

```
library(dplyr); library(slider)
xdata %>%
  filter(!is.na(start_date)) %>%
  mutate(avg = slide_index_dbl(values, date, .after = 4, mean)) %>%
  select(start_date = date, avg) %>% 
  right_join(xdata ) %>% 
  select(date, values, everything()) %>%
  arrange(date) %>% View()
```

Comment: Jon, thank you. Your answer has real promise. But I don't quite understand what it's doing. If, in the creation of xdata , change "values=rnorm(365*3, 1,5)" to "values=seq(1, 365*3)".

Running this example using your code, the result of the first calculation of avg is avg=21 on date=2015-01-19, start_date=02-02-2015.

My understanding is the slide_index_dbl function is calc'ing the mean starting at start_date=02-02-2015. 

However, values=32 on 02-02-2015. avg is too low.  Shouldn't the call to slide_index_dbl calc the avg of values from 02-02-15 to 02-06-2015?

Comment: It's currently indexing by `start_date`, averaging `values` for everything that has the current `start_date` up to and including 5 days later. So in this case it's grabbing rows 18:24, with dates of 1/19 to 1/24, all with `start_date` of 2/02, and averaging 18:24 = 21. What output are you expecting? Can you walk through an example?

Comment: Edited answer, what you expected now?

Comment: I get it.   What I'd like is the average of values for 5 days starting where date=start_date. In other words, start_date defines the first date of the 5 day averaging period of values over date + (date + days(5)), to use lubridate syntax.   Does that make sense?

Comment: Jon, I edited the original question for clarity.  Thx.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I think my edited answer does that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229542/discussion-between-jfd-and-jon-spring).

Comment: Thanks Jon for your help. I accepted your answer.   I found, however, that I needed to add the .before clause.   As in: 

xdata %>%
  filter(!is.na(start_date)) %>%
  mutate(avg = slide_index_dbl(values, date, mean, .before=1, .after = 5)) %>%
  select(start_date = date, avg) %>% 
  right_join(xdata ) %>% 
  select(date, values, everything()) %>%
  arrange(date)

Comment: Upon review, I think it should've been `.after = 4`, and I bet you don't need the `.before = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

This places a NA in the rows with the month of the start date being the same as the month of date. Note that in your toy dataset the days are always spaced 7 days apart, so the code doesn't actually capture any days in the next five days.

```
val=numeric()
for (i in 1:nrow(xdata)) {
  if (is.na(xdata$start_date[i]) | month((xdata$date)[i])==month((xdata$start_date)[i])) {
    val[i]=NA
  } else {
    dat=filter(xdata, start_date >= (xdata$start_date)[i] & start_date<= (xdata$start_date)[i]+5)
    val[i]=mean(dat$values)
  }
}
xdata2=mutate(xdata, val)
```